# How can I get average of the multidimensional matrix datas in Julia?

Tags: julia, bioinformatics, calculation

Can I get the average of multidimensional matrix data in the same place in Julia?
Such as:

```
A=[
2 4 6
8 10 12
]

B=[
4 6 8
10 12 14
]

Average=[
3 5 7
9 11 13
]
```

If I have a matrix file, can I get the average of all the data in the same place in the matrix file?
In the same row and column?

And also, I cannot use any statistics method in my data. (using Statistics)

Here is my code.

```
julia> using BioStructures

julia> struc0=read("ranked_0.pdb",PDB)
ProteinStructure ranked_0.pdb with 1 models, 1 chains (A), 398 residues, 6267 atoms

julia> struc1=read("ranked_1.pdb",PDB)
ProteinStructure ranked_1.pdb with 1 models, 1 chains (A), 398 residues, 6267 atoms

#PDB is protein structure file
#calphaselector collects alpha-carbon in protein structure

julia> calphas1=collectatoms(struc1['A'],calphaselector)
398-element Vector{AbstractAtom}:
 Atom CA with serial 5, coordinates [-48.92, 44.228, -7.122]
 Atom CA with serial 22, coordinates [-45.297, 43.116, -7.895]
 Atom CA with serial 44, coordinates [-44.734, 41.122, -11.106]
 Atom CA with serial 68, coordinates [-43.19, 37.683, -11.734]
 Atom CA with serial 90, coordinates [-40.072, 37.975, -13.951]
 Atom CA with serial 109, coordinates [-39.962, 34.961, -16.27]
 Atom CA with serial 120, coordinates [-36.574, 35.287, -18.039]
 Atom CA with serial 142, coordinates [-36.609, 33.35, -21.312]
 Atom CA with serial 152, coordinates [-34.149, 30.463, -21.787]
 Atom CA with serial 171, coordinates [-32.469, 30.904, -25.188]
 Atom CA with serial 190, coordinates [-32.407, 27.558, -27.034]
 Atom CA with serial 201, coordinates [-28.96, 27.662, -28.654]
 Atom CA with serial 211, coordinates [-28.549, 24.452, -30.698]
 ⋮
 Atom CA with serial 6078, coordinates [-24.236, -1.604, 12.74]
 Atom CA with serial 6093, coordinates [-26.218, 1.577, 11.906]
 Atom CA with serial 6117, coordinates [-24.924, 4.783, 13.587]
 Atom CA with serial 6136, coordinates [-27.904, 7.205, 13.764]
 Atom CA with serial 6147, coordinates [-28.211, 10.904, 14.654]
 Atom CA with serial 6154, coordinates [-25.655, 12.413, 17.087]
 Atom CA with serial 6168, coordinates [-24.017, 9.206, 18.385]
 Atom CA with serial 6179, coordinates [-20.62, 7.793, 19.378]
 Atom CA with serial 6193, coordinates [-19.557, 4.234, 18.472]
 Atom CA with serial 6214, coordinates [-16.767, 2.846, 20.702]
 Atom CA with serial 6228, coordinates [-14.132, 0.846, 18.748]
 Atom CA with serial 6247, coordinates [-11.916, 0.05, 21.82]


julia> calphas0=collectatoms(struc0['A'],calphaselector)
398-element Vector{AbstractAtom}:
 Atom CA with serial 5, coordinates [-36.089, 66.106, 25.299]
 Atom CA with serial 22, coordinates [-33.821, 64.881, 22.365]
 Atom CA with serial 44, coordinates [-33.557, 62.444, 20.056]
 Atom CA with serial 68, coordinates [-32.879, 58.931, 18.504]
 Atom CA with serial 90, coordinates [-29.619, 58.508, 16.472]
 Atom CA with serial 109, coordinates [-30.364, 57.074, 13.005]
 Atom CA with serial 120, coordinates [-28.582, 54.105, 11.366]
 Atom CA with serial 142, coordinates [-25.95, 54.934, 8.729]
 Atom CA with serial 152, coordinates [-25.746, 52.003, 6.279]
 Atom CA with serial 171, coordinates [-22.186, 52.037, 4.888]
 Atom CA with serial 190, coordinates [-22.536, 50.445, 1.448]
 Atom CA with serial 201, coordinates [-19.07, 48.955, 0.906]
 Atom CA with serial 211, coordinates [-19.304, 47.721, -2.701]
 ⋮
 Atom CA with serial 6078, coordinates [-30.501, 3.783, 9.927]
 Atom CA with serial 6093, coordinates [-30.924, 7.529, 10.661]
 Atom CA with serial 6117, coordinates [-28.57, 8.891, 13.374]
 Atom CA with serial 6136, coordinates [-30.304, 12.0, 14.818]
 Atom CA with serial 6147, coordinates [-29.161, 14.746, 17.23]
 Atom CA with serial 6154, coordinates [-26.384, 13.957, 19.761]
 Atom CA with serial 6168, coordinates [-26.4, 10.132, 19.458]
 Atom CA with serial 6179, coordinates [-23.963, 7.201, 19.425]
 Atom CA with serial 6193, coordinates [-24.374, 4.256, 17.037]
 Atom CA with serial 6214, coordinates [-22.595, 1.092, 18.252]
 Atom CA with serial 6228, coordinates [-20.864, -0.796, 15.39]
 Atom CA with serial 6247, coordinates [-19.446, -3.617, 17.623]
# calculate Distance between alpha-carbon

function DistanceMap(el1::StructuralElementOrList,
                el2::StructuralElementOrList)
    dists = zeros(length(el1), length(el2))
    for (i, subel1) in enumerate(el1)
        for (j, subel2) in enumerate(el2)
            dists[i, j] = distance(subel1, subel2)
        end
    end
    return DistanceMap(dists)
end

function DistanceMap(el::StructuralElementOrList)
    dists = zeros(length(el), length(el))
    el_list = collect(el)
    for i in 1:length(el)
        for j in 1:(i - 1)
            dist = distance(el_list[i], el_list[j])
            dists[i, j] = dist
            dists[j, i] = dist
        end
    end
    return DistanceMap(dists)
end
```

```
julia> dm0=DistanceMap(calphas0)
Distance map of size (398, 398)
julia> dm1=DistanceMap(calphas1)
Distance map of size (398, 398)


#Here is some Distance Map Data

julia> dm0[1,3]
6.87824955929922

julia> dm1[1,1]
0.0

julia> dm1[1,3]
6.560646919321296

julia> println(typeof(size(dm0)))
Tuple{Int64, Int64}



julia>using Statistics

julia> mean(dm0,dims=1)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching mean(::DistanceMap; dims=1)
Closest candidates are:
  mean(::Any) at /builddir/build/BUILD/julia-1.6.5/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/Statistics/src/Statistics.jl:44 got unsupported keyword argument "dims"
  mean(::Any, ::AbstractArray; dims) at /builddir/build/BUILD/julia-1.6.5/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/Statistics/src/Statistics.jl:104
  mean(::Any, ::Any) at /builddir/build/BUILD/julia-1.6.5/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/Statistics/src/Statistics.jl:61 got unsupported keyword argument "dims"
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL[19]:1
```

#I don't know the reason that the `mean` function doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
julia> foo = [
       1 2 3
       4 5 6
       ]
2×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2  3
 4  5  6

julia> bar = [
       8 2 7
       9 6 3
       ]
2×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 8  2  7
 9  6  3

julia> (foo+bar)/2
2×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 4.5  2.0  5.0
 6.5  5.5  4.5
```

In your case, In the last phase of the `DistanceMap` function, you're returning the function object, which isn't what you want to do apparently. So the last line of the function should be replaced with the `return dists`:

```
function DistanceMap(el::StructuralElementOrList)
    dists = zeros(length(el), length(el))
    # do jobs...
    return dists
end

function DistanceMap(el1::StructuralElementOrList, el2::StructuralElementOrList)
    dists = zeros(length(el1), length(el2))
    # do jobs...
    return dists
end
```

Then, the `(dm0+dm1)/2` will give you what you expect.

---

**Using the `mean` function with specified dimension (specifically related to Statistics.jl package)**
It seems to me you don't know how the `mean(dm0,dims=1)` works. Say I have this simple `2x3` matrix:

```
julia> foo = [
       1 2 3
       4 5 6
       ]
2×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2  3
 4  5  6
```

We want to observe how the `mean(foo, dims=1)` works in this case. First, I should mention that performing the `mean` function on a collection of values calculates the mean of all the elements:

```
julia> mean(foo)
3.5
```

But what happens when we specify the dimension we want to take the `mean`? In this case, `mean` calculate the average value in the given matrix over a dimension. For example, If I want to take the mean of `foo` over the first dimension (each column), the following shows what is going to happen:

```
julia> mean(foo, dims=1)
1×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 2.5  3.5  4.5
```

[image]

Comment: `(foo.+bar)./2` is probably preferable over `(foo+bar)/2`.